Show that $ \lim_{n\to\infty} nP(|X_1|>\epsilon \sqrt{n})=0 $.
Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $E|X_i|^2<\infty$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that for every $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} nP(|X_1|>\epsilon \sqrt{n})=0
$$
and that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\max_{1\le k\le n}X_k\to 0
$$
in probability.

If we use Chebyshev's inequality directly,
$$
nP(|X_1|>\epsilon \sqrt{n})\le \frac{E|X_1|^2}{\epsilon^2}
$$
So we cannot get the limit $0$...

Use Chebyshev for $X_1^2$ and ${\epsilon}^2 n^2$

$ EX_1^{2}1_{|X_1|>\epsilon \sqrt n}\ge \epsilon^{2} nP(|X_1|>\epsilon \sqrt n)$ so $nP(|X_1|>\epsilon \sqrt n) \le \frac 1 {\epsilon^{2}}EX_1^{2}1_{|X_1|>\epsilon \sqrt n} \to 0$ by DCT.
$P(\frac   1{\sqrt n} \max |X_i| >\epsilon ) \le P(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}(|X_i|>\epsilon \sqrt n)\le \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} P(  |X_i| >\epsilon \sqrt n)= n P(  |X_1| >\epsilon \sqrt n) \to 0. $

Your first line contains an error.

@UmbertoP. Sure. Thanks for pointing out.
